# How do I get Azure Graph Explorer to return the GUID value of subscriptionId, instead of translating it to a Name?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-graph

I'm working to export a list of Azure resources (let's say VMs), along with their corresponding SubscriptionId's (the GUID).

Attempting to do that via Graph Explorer appears to be translating and returning the subscription Name in a field called `subscriptionId`.  In the results there's a "Details" button on the Name; when clicked that button shows both the name and Id.

Here's the Graph Explorer query:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| project name, subscriptionId
```

And here's the results:

[image: Screenshot of Azure Resource Graph Explorer returning a Subscription's Name when subscriptionId is projected]

how do I get `subscriptionId` to return the GUID based Id, instead of the subscription Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get Azure Graph Explorer to return the GUID value of subscriptionId, instead of translating it to a Name?

You need to turn off  Formatted results like below:

[image]

Then you will get sub id.

If you on you will get results as below:

[image]